# PHP: What does -> appearing more than once in a statement mean?

Tags: php, object, operators, instance-variables

I understand that in `$page->$blocks= 'blocks';` $page is an object, $blocks is its field, and here we are assigning the string 'blocks' to the instance variable $blocks which belongs to the instance $page.

But what about `$this -> blocks -> function();`

*Functions do not belong to fields but objects. Neither can objects have objects.*

**So what does the above statement mean? Doesn't it say: *Call the function() of the instance blocks of the current instance ($this)* ?**

**And then what does the following interpret in simple English?**

```
$this->page->blocks->region_has_content($displayregion, $this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Neither can objects have objects

This is false. Objects can (and often do!) have references to other objects, and this is exactly what is going on, you are calling a method on an object which is referenced inside different object

```
$a->b->c->d()
```

means that you are calling method `d()` on object referenced by field `c` in object which is referenced by field `b` in `$a`

Answer (score 1):

It means, that this field is another object, which has the function "function()"